# Jquery preventDefault is not working for many submits

Tags: jquery, submit, preventdefault

I'm trying to bind two submits events, and prevent the second one.

Example:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){ 
    alert(1); 
    //if some condition cut the submit events
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('form').submit(function(){ 
    alert(2); 
    return false;    
});
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/da3aB/

Comment: Worked fine. What was wrong with your fiddle? It didn't submit.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: He wants to suppress the second alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to tell jQuery not to call other events that were registered for that element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/da3aB/2/)

Comment: really fast your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Order of the attaching the event handlers is also very important here. `stopImmediatePropagation` function should be in the first event handler. http://jsfiddle.net/da3aB/7/